# In TypeScript, how to prevent a method from being called on derived class?

Tags: class, typescript, subclass, derived-class

There are three classes.

```
// in external library, which I don't want to modify
class ComponentBase {
    // I want calling this to be disallowed
    forceUpdate() {}
}

class ComponentBase_MyVersion extends ComponentBase {
    // I want subclasses to always call this, instead of forceUpdate()
    Update() {}
}

class MyComponent extends ComponentBase_MyVersion {
    DoSomething() {
        // I want this to be disallowed
        this.forceUpdate();

        // forcing the subclass to call this instead
        this.Update();
    }
}
```

How can I accomplish this, with changes only to `ComponentBase_MyVersion`?

Is there a way to "hide" a base-class member?

Or perhaps a way to override the definition -- like with the "new" keyword in C# -- letting me mangle the method definition to at least make warnings appear when attempting to call it?

Answer (score 5):

The OOP does not allow you to do this kind of method cancellation. You can impleement this funcion on your class with an Exception like you suggested, or use a composition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Example 1:

```
class ComponentBase {
    forceUpdate() {}
}

class ComponentBase_MyVersion extends ComponentBase {
    Update() {}
    forceUpdate() {
        throw new Error("Do not call this. Call Update() instead.");
    }
}

class MyComponent extends ComponentBase_MyVersion {
    DoSomething() {
        // wil raise an exception
        this.forceUpdate();
        this.Update();
    }
}
```

Example 2 (composition):

```
class ComponentBase {
    forceUpdate() {}
}

class ComponentBase_MyVersion {
    private _component: ComponentBase = ...;
    Update() {}
    // expose _component desired members ...
}

class MyComponent extends ComponentBase_MyVersion {
    DoSomething() {
        // compilation error
        this.forceUpdate();
        this.Update();
    }
}
```

I hope I helped.

Answer (score 2):

Encapsulate implementation by replacing inheritance with composition [Delegation Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern)

You can do this by adding the `private` access modifier on the `forceUpdate` method. This will result in all the subclasses being unable to access `forceUpdate`. However TypeScript does not support package access modifiers, but you can do this by replacing inheritance with composition.

```
class ComponentBase {
    forceUpdate() {
    }
}

class ComponentBase_MyVersion {
    // Replace inheritance with composition.
    private component: ComponentBase;

    Update() {
        this.component.forceUpdate();
    }
}

class MyComponent extends ComponentBase_MyVersion {
    DoSomething() {
        // Now subclass can't access forceUpdate method
        this.Update();
    }
}
```

Use a `symbol` in order to prevent external access to the method.
If you don't want to replace inheritance with composition, you can use `Symbol` to define a method. If your target is `es5` you must configure `tsconfig.json` `compilerOptions.lib` to include `es2015.symbol`. Because every `symbol` is unique, any external module will not be able to obtain the symbol and access the method.

```
// libs.ts
let forceUpdate = Symbol("forceUpdate");
export class ComponentBase {
    [forceUpdate]() {
    }
}

export default class ComponentBase_MyVersion extends ComponentBase {
    Update() {
        this[forceUpdate]();
    }
}


// test.ts
import ComponentBase_MyVersion from "./libs";
class MyComponent extends ComponentBase_MyVersion {
    DoSomething() {
        // Now subclass can't access the forceUpdate method.
        this.Update();
    }
}
```

Comment: When I do that I get a compile error (in TypeScript 2.1.5): "Class 'ComponentBase_MyVersion' incorrectly extends base class 'ComponentBase'.
  Property 'forceUpdate' is private in type 'ComponentBase_MyVersion' but not in type 'ComponentBase'."

Comment: OP said they want to accomplish this by only making changes to `ComponentBase_MyVersion`.

Comment: @Venryx you can do this by replace inheritance with composite. delegate `ComponentBase_MyVersion` methods to the `ComponentBase`

Comment: @Venryx I have found another solution to solve your problem,I updated my asnwer & fix answer when I misread your question.

Comment: @holi-java Interesting solution! It's not usable in my case, since I don't have (convenient) access to modify the `ComponentBase` class, but this would be helpful for custom base-classes that you only want visible one class-level down. (ie, usable only by a direct subclass)

Comment: @Venryx ^_^,in your situation I suggest you use [diullei](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1614863/diullei) the first solution if you don't want to replace inheritance with composition.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way that seems to work -- that is, which causes warnings to appear when someone attempts to call `forceUpdate()` on a subclass instance.

```
forceUpdate(_: ()=>"Do not call this. Call Update() instead.") {
    throw new Error("Do not call this. Call Update() instead.");
}
```

Now when I write `new MyComponent().forceUpdate()`, I get a compiler error, with the warning message containing a description telling me to use `Update()` instead.

**EDIT**: Apparently this only works because the base class already had this definition:

```
forceUpdate(callBack?: () => any): void;
```

If instead the base method is defined with no arguments originally (as in the OP), the above solution doesn't work.

However, if you have a case like mine (where there's an optional property like that, which you can narrow the return-type of), it works fine. (not sure if this return-type-narrowing is a bug, or intended)

Comment: To use it, you will need to change the signature from `forceUpdate()` at the base class, and you don't want to do this.

Comment: @Diullei Oh, it looks like you're right, for the OP example. However, in my actual use case it works, because the real forceUpdate() method accepts one (optional) argument of type `()=>any`. My override just narrows the requirements to `()=>"random string"` -- which doesn't itself cause an error, but causes one to show when normal usage of the function is attempted. So the solution above doesn't work in the general case, but does work in the case I had. (so might still be useful to mention, for other viewers)

Comment: Great, for the general solution, following your original question, the composition approach seems to be the answer, but I'm happy you found a way to go with your code :)